# How to use BigQuery as sink in Apache Flink?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-flink

Is it possible to use JDBC Connector to write the Flink Datastream to Bigquery or any other options?

New to Apache Flink, any suggestions/examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is currently not supported as a JDBC dialect by Flink. An overview of the currently supported versions can be found at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/

I'm not aware of a BigQuery sink being available. That implies that in order to write to BigQuery, you would have to create your own custom sink.